# WHM Wordpress admin-ajax.php High CPU Load: Error "-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, cpu-usage, whm

To all the awesome gurus out there:

I have just migrated to a new VPS server and noticed admin-ajax.php using up a very high amount of CPU% in WHM and when I traced the process I can see plenty of access error as shown below:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU6Vr.png)

```
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/dynamic-content/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/element/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/options/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/pro/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/regions/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/styling/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/templating/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/classic/builder/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    access("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/classic/controls/class-control-textarea.php", F_OK) = 0
    lstat("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/classic/controls/class-control-textarea.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=262, ...}) = 0
    open("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/includes/classes/classic/controls/class-control-textarea.php", O_RDONLY) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=262, ...}) = 0
    read(5, "<?php\nclass Cornerstone_Control_"..., 262) = 262
    fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=1}) = 0
    fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_UNLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=1}) = 0
    close(5)
```

As you can see, it cycles through a whole directory before finding the file and then closing the process. (this is in a single process where it happens about 400 times in that one process)

I'm concerned that this is the issue that is causing the CPU overload, and it's causing my webpage to load really slowly frontend and backend.

I am also in the midst of upgrading my server but here's my server spec below:

> OS: Linux
>
> CPU: 2 Cores Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz
>
> RAM: 2GB
>
> PHP Handler: suphp
>
> CMS: Wordpress Multisite

I have never had this issue prior to my upgrade to the VPS server and I am concerned that this may be a performance related issue.

I'm open to any suggestions here, thank you guys in advance and pardon my inexperience on Linux servers

Comment: Please check whether all the files in the cornerstone plugin are in the server, if not, please reinstall it

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Ken, the required files are all in the server and this is not limited to just one plugin, it spans across other plugins as well :/